# i tried write the first code in a different way. first is okay second also runs but i got a " nontype object is not callable error". why is that?

Tags: python, decorator

in this python code here i get error "nonetype object is callable". why is that? thanks

```
`#firstcode

def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("============")
        func()
        print("============")
    return wrap

def print_text():
    print("Hello world!")

print_text = decor(print_text)
print_text()

#secondcode

def wrap(func):
    print("============")
    func()
    print("============")


def print_text():
    print("Hello world!")

print_text = wrap(print_text)
print_text()`
```

i tried to write code in another way and i got error. actually maybe the problem is that wrap function does not return anything here and i call it to reassign print_text. but i couldn't understand it well. any suggestions?

Comment: `wrap(print_text)` does not return anything, therefore you cannot call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second code, `wrap` does not return anything i.e. it returns None.

Thus:

```py
print_text = wrap(print_text)
```

Is equivalent to:

```py
print_text = None
```

You are trying to call `print_text` like a function but it is `None`.

Comment: ah okay. then the problem is that my reassigning is illegal. i got it, thanks